# Use of comment_reply_link_args filter

Tags: filters, comments, author, title, comment-form

i am trying to create a filter like this

```
add_filter('comment_reply_link_args','change_author_title');
function change_author_title( $args ) {
  $defaults = array(
        'add_below'     => 'comment',
        'respond_id'    => 'respond',
        'reply_text'    => __( 'Reply' ),
        /* translators: Comment reply button text. %s: Comment author name. */
        'reply_to_text' => __( 'THIS TEXT' ),
        'login_text'    => __( 'Log in to Reply' ),
        'max_depth'     => 0,
        'depth'         => 0,
        'before'        => '',
        'after'         => '',
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    return $args;
}
```

**What i actually need is to filter the *'reply_to_text'* from the $defaults array.**

The reason behind this is that i created a filter with *get_comment_author*

```
add_filter('get_comment_author', 'my_comment_author', 10, 2);
function my_comment_author( $author, $comment_ID ) {
    if (! is_admin()) {
    // Get the comment ID from WP_Query
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
    $authoremail = get_comment_author_email( $comment); 
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $comment->comment_author_email );

    if (! email_exists($authoremail)) {
        if(mb_strlen($comment->comment_author, 'UTF-8')>13){
        $author = mb_substr($comment->comment_author,0,13, 'UTF-8').'.'; }
    } else {
        if( ! empty( $user->first_name ) ){
        $author = $user->first_name;  }
        else {
        return $author;  }
    } }

    return $author;
}
```

and i would like to pass the same output in $defaults array 'reply_to_text'.

Could someone give me a tip?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, something like this?

```php
add_filter( 'comment_reply_link_args', 'change_author_title', 10, 2 );
function change_author_title( $args, $comment ) {
    $args['reply_to_text'] = 'Reply to ' . get_comment_author( $comment );
    return $args;
}
```

Explanation: I changed the function declaration so that it accepts the [second parameter (`$comment`)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_reply_link_args/#parameters) which is the comment object (a `WP_Comment` instance), then I simply call the [`get_comment_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author/) which fires the `get_comment_author` hook. That way, your `my_comment_author()` function would be called and then you'd get the same author name for use with the `reply_to_text` arg.

Comment: Thank you very much , this is what i was trying to do .